# Database Design: I have a child table which might be used from more than one parent table (one-to-one). How do I design its schema

Tags: mysql, database-design

Imagine I have a child table called `offers`. `offers` can be referred from multiple tables such as `purchase`, `membership`, etc. Notice that in future, there can be more tables it will be referenced from.

Purchases and memberships are already present in the database and they will always be created before the corresponding offer object. Think of it like a purchase X may provide an offer Y (one to one)

In order to implement this in a relational schema, I thought of two possible options.

**Option 1**

`offers` table will not have any references. instead, `purchase` table and `membership` table will have a column named `offer_id` which references the `offer` table. As given below

```
   table offers { 
      id,
      offer_name, 
   }

   table purchase { 
      id,
      ..other fields,
      offer_id fk(offers),
   }

   table membership { 
      id,
      ..other fields,
      offer_id fk(offers),
   }
```

**Option 2**

`offers` table will contain a `type` field which refers the type of offer (`purchase`, `membership`, etc..) and there will be multiple nullable foreign keys referring to each table.

```
   table offers { 
      id,
      offer_name, 
      type enum(purchase, membership,
      purchase_id fk(purchases) NULL, 
      membership_id fk(memberships) NULL,
   }

   table purchase { 
      id,
      ..other fields,
   }

   table membership { 
      id,
      ..other fields,
   }
```

I felt that Option 1 is the simplest way to do it and also the right way. But it feels like going against database design principles (Parent should not refer child, etc..).

What should be the right way to do this? If I go with option 1, what will go wrong?

Comment: I would probably have linking tables for each offer type.

Comment: What is the logical order of creating offers vs purchase / membership, etc?

Comment: @Shadow Purchases or memberships will be created first (Imagine these tables are already in the database), 

Offers can be created later as well as not created at all.

Comment: @Strawberry Could you give a reasoning?, What I felt the problem with  that approach is that whenever I need to add offer to another table, that will involve creation of new table, then all the code referencing that table, etc. But I would love to hear alternative thoughts on this!

Comment: Can offers have different properties based on the type of entity they relate to (apart from the FK)?

Comment: @Shadow Nope, they are completely independent on their own.

Comment: You wrote in your question that this is a 1:1 relationship, can you confirm this? Are you sure that the same offer cannot apply to multiple other entities?

Comment: @Shadow Maybe `offer` is a wrong example. (This is not the actual table, i made up the examples).  Yes it is indeed a one to one relationship. Think of it like for a particular membership, there's one particular offer available and only one.

Comment: @IrshadPI True, but you're not likely to need to do that very often.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you create the `offer` entity **after** the `purchase` or `membership` entities, `offer` is the child entity and should therefore have the foreign key(s) to the parent table.

I know it is tempting to do it the other way around, but semantics are important in a database design:

1. If your FK is in the parent entities, then you run the risk of having orphan offers, that do not belong to any entities. You cannot enforce integrity through FKs.
2. You cannot prevent through standard database techniques that 1 offer is assigned to multiple entities. You need to write additional application code to enforce this rule.
3. Anybody looking at your ERD will come to the wrong initial conclusion regarding the nature of the relationship, so you have to provide additional explanation to every new colleague.
4. If you use an ORM on top of your database schema, the ORM would again interpret the relationship incorrectly, setting up classes and relationships following the FKs. Again, additional explanations will be necessary.

You have three options designing the foreign key(s) in the `offer` table to follow option 2:

1. Each parent has a separate FK field. Advantage is that it is clear which parent entity the child belongs to and it is easy to enforce referential integrity. Drawback is that you need to create as many fields as parent entities and requires an alter table to add a new one. Works well, if you have a limited and stable number of parent entities.
2. Use a `type` and a `parent_id` field combination. The type field tells you which parent the record belongs to. This is the opposite of the previous solution - flexible to add new parent types, but enforcing referential integrity through database tool will not be simple!
3. Use separate offer tables for each parent type. This design can be useful if you plan to diverge the various offers by type.